# URI::InvalidURIError for a URI that's not in my power to encode

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm using [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to unshorten short URIs and I happened upon:

`HTTParty.get('http://bit.ly/19NoFfn', limit: 50 )`

which when expanded yields:

`https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PhpSpec Snippets`

which obviously throws a: URI::InvalidURIError.

Would it be possible to pass some parameter to httparty so that it would automatically try to encode URIs before trying to follow them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sort of solved my issue:

```
def unshorten(uri)
  begin
    response = HTTParty.get(uri, limit: 50)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError => error
    bad_uri = error.message.match(/^bad\sURI\(is\snot\sURI\?\)\:\s(.*)$/)[1]
    good_uri = URI.encode bad_uri
    response = self.unshorten good_uri
  end
  response
end
```

I don't feel particularly comfortable fetching the URI from the error message string but it seems there's no other way. Or is there? :)

Comment: Heh. I had exactly the same thought as you and ended up here, at your answer — "I can solve it like this but surely it's not the best way"